# iPhone 6 (IOS 11) Picture library storage wont go down

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud

So for a while now I've had little to no space on my phone because of my picture library, I couldn't even back it up. So today i decided to delete upwards of 700 photos and 70 videos. After deleting them in the storage nothing has changed, I have disabled iCloud Sharing and no, before you say anything, there are no photos in my recently deleted.

Comment: It can take several hours for the iCloud sync to take place (iPhone on wifi and plugged into power) so large-scale changes such as this might not need immediately evident. How long have you been waiting for the changes to show up?

Comment: Did you also clear 'Recently Deleted'? Otherwise they'll stay for 30 days.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yeah, in the last line the OP said there is nothing in recently deleted. That's what I would have thought of too.

Comment: oops, D'oh.....